# Windows 8 and BIOS won't boot after installing Linux

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, fedora, fedora-20

I've recently been dual booting Windows 8 and Fedora 20 (and one point Ubuntu). My Fedora kernel wouldn't load in GRUB one day so I decided to reinstall Fedora using a live USB (my laptop doesn't have an optical drive). Unfortunately when I was freeing up space on my partition I may of deleted something I shouldn't of, because now when I boot up the boot manager gives me only the Fedora GRUB boot option. I can't even access my BIOS or recovery mode. The only command that works on boot is <kbd>F12</kbd> which brings me to a option-less boot manager.

I've been going through forums and forums to figure out what I may have done. but unfortunately I'm a bit new to Linux so I'm unable to pin point exactly what I've done wrong. I've installed a Windows 8 ISO on a live USB and the boot manager (and GRUB) won't pick it up. I'm at a loss. Luckily my new Fedora installation is working and I know my Windows partition is still intact since I'm able to mount on it and take files I need.

Here's my output for `fdisks -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FAF7B893-EA9B-4853-9CE0-487E0AE01B25

Device      Start       End         Size    Type
/dev/sda1   2048        821247      400M    Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2   821248      1230847     200M    EFI System
/dev/sda3   1435648     1697791     128M    Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4   1697792     1187741695  565.6G  Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   1570736128  1775534079  97.7G   Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   1775536128  1814597631  18.6G   Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7   1814597632  1916997631  48.8G   Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8   1187741696  1188765695  500M    Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9   1918896128  1953523711  16.5G   Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda10  1290141696  1291165695  500M    Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda11  1291165696  1570736127  133.3G  Linux LVM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the below two options:

1. Use Windows installation disc to repair the boot loader (this will though overwrite the current linux bootloader and make Fedora not usable, you later need to manually setup Grub)
2. Boot into Fedora and edit the Grub entry to include Win 8 in boot options (refer link [Add boot entry to Grub in Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/46803/how-to-dual-boot-windows-81-and-fedora-20/))